# FlashDevelop Classpath Definition not Found

Tags: flashdevelop, gsap

I downloaded greensock-as3.zip and set up 'com' folder classpath but I get this error messages

```
Error: Access of undefined property TweenLite.
Error: Definition com.greensock:TweenLite could not be found.
```

But the funny part is that I can reach TweenLite when I write `import com.greensock.TweenLite;`

Do you have any idea about that problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have your library in: `path/to/tweenlite/src/com/...`

then classpath should be: `path/to/tweenlite/src/`

FlashDevelop is just too nice with wrong classpaths.